# Разница между .apk и signed .apk

Tags: android

В чем разница между *.apk* и signed *.apk*? При установке обоих разницы не нашел.

Comment: А вы, извините, в Интернете вообще искали ответ? Например, в [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: @Regent, обфускация и подпись сертификатом между собой абсолютно не связаны. Обфускация полностью на усмотрение разработчика. Понятно, что отладочные APK никто обфускатором не прогоняет. А подписывать APK надо всегда, чтобы установить на устройство или эмулятор. По умолчанию, Android SDK подписывает автоматически сгенерированным debug сертификатом.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я и не писал, что они связаны. Я писал как раз про то, что отладочный _.apk_ редко кто обфусцирует. А вот про то, что отладочный подписан с помощью _debug.keystore_ я, скажем прямо, не знал. Но с этим уже разобрались в комментариях к ответу. Мой комментарий под вопросом надо было раньше удалить, да.

Answer (score 13):

Несмотря на очевидную проблемность вопроса, вопрос таки имеет право на жизнь. На самом то деле если быть точным есть 3 варианта подписывания/неподписывания APK (а не 2 как многие думают):

1. Классический self-signed APK, когда приложение подписывается т.н. debug ключом. Debug ключ можно либо сгенерировать самостоятельно, либо он генерируется автоматически при установке Android SDK. Ключ лежит в каталоге: `HOME/.android/debug.keystore`. Debug ключ вполне себе такой нормальный ключ за вычетом того, что с таким ключом невозможно выставить приложение в любой нормальный маркет - a.k.a Google Play, Amazon, Samsung и проч. Однако, приложение с такой подписью можно устанавливать практически на любое реальное устройство, эмулятор и третьеразрядные маркеты (типа blackmart и проч.). Скорее всего ТС имеет ввиду под *неподписанным* именно этот вариант.
2. Т.н. релиз APK подписывается стандартным девелоперским ключом, ключ генерируется самостоятельно 1 раз при создании девелоперского аккаунта в Google Play - потеря ключа равносильна потере девелоперского аккаунта. Как уже говорилось выше: без подписи таким ключом нормальные маркеты приложение не принимают. Приложение подписанное таким ключом можно поставить куда угодно и как угодно: устройства, маркеты, эмуляторы.
3. Некоторые IDE умеют генерировать т.н. unsigned APK - то есть APK вообще без подписи каким либо ключом. На самом то деле подписывание APK это последний этап сборки, так что всегда можно выцепить (если знать как) неподписанный экземпляр APK. Например, в Android Studio неподписанный экземпляр APK лежит в: `build/outputs/apk/*-unsigned.apk`. Неподписанный APK невозможно поставить ни в один нормальный девайс (ну может в левые китайские разве что), не говоря уже о маркетах. Неподписанный APK можно поставить только на эмулятор.

P.S. Зачем нужна подпись? Дело в том, что подпись дает четкую привязку приложение-девелопер-аккаунт. А в аккаунте девелопера (согласно последним веяниям) - указан домашний адрес, телефончик и проч. интересные детали бурной личной жизни разработчика. Так что случись что, за разработчиком сразу придут компетентные органы :)

Comment: По поводу _зачем нужна подпись_: вторым важным моментом является уверенность в том, что данный _.apk_ - от того же разработчика.

Comment: И все же APK, подписанный девелоперским сертификатом не отличается ничем от АПК, подписанного обычным сертификатом.

Comment: @Barmaley, я за мир :), но позволю себе указать на неточности в Вашем посте. 1. Все сертификаты, и debug, и release, являются self-signed. Поэтому и все АРК являются такими же. 2. release сертификатов может быть миллион у одного девелопера, по одному на каждое из его миллиона приложений. 3. Потеря сертификата означает потерю контороля над приложениями, подписанными этим ключем. Но никак не над дев. аккаунтом! Ничто вам не мешает удалить его из Google Play и создать как новое с новым сертификатом.

Comment: P.S. Подпись ничего не привязывает, вы можете подарить приложение вместе с сертификатом другу, и он загрузит его под своим аккаунтом без проблем, если вы у себя его удалите. Сертификат всего лишь гарантирует, что создатель и тот кто загружает новые версии приложения один и тот же девелопер.

Comment: Так то так, но речь идет о том, что по сертификату друга - можно его вычислить