# Принципиальная разница между app-debug и app-release android?

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение на андроид. Я его тестировал на разных эмуляторах, и так повелось что я постоянно генерировал app-debug, или как такое приложение принято называть дебаг-версия. Эту версию приложения я с легкостью ставил на много реальных устройств, но потом два устройства повели себя не просто странно, а вообще непонятно. Что именно произошло - приложение не грузило ресурсы, вообще никакие - текст картинки,и может что еще, я не видел. Работать с этим приложением на проблемном, как я думал телефоне было невозможно так-как приложение слетало, и указывало что ошибка в строковом ресурсе, который на остальных устройствах был нормальным. Более подробно можете увидеть информацию по поводу этих проблем в моих вопросах: [Объясните ошибку android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865114/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-android). Дальше я сделал релизную версию приложения, и моя программа работала на всех устройствах. Дальше я начал искать информацию по этому поводу и нашел такой вопрос: [Разница между .apk и signed .apk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432098/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-apk-%D0%B8-signed-apk). Ответ на этот вопрос частично ответил на мои некоторые вопросы, но мне все равно не очень понятно что-же так сильно меняется в приложении после нормального подписания, ведь после подписания приложение нашло все ресурсы и работало отлично.

Я буду очень благодарен если мне объяснят отличия, на моем примере с моим приложением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый - отлаживаемый, а второй - нет. Это означает, что первый из них выведет все ваши `Log.d`, а релизная версия - нет. Кроме того, по умолчанию debug-версии компилируются без `ProGuard`, тогда как release-сборки скомпилированы с использованием `ProGuard` по умолчанию.

Comment: а что такое `ProGuard`?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/proguard.php